# Automating telric controls with selenium rc and junit

Tags: java, selenium, junit, selenium-rc, testng

I need to automate a web application that is built in asp.net.This is mandatory that I have to use Selenium RC along with Junit or TestNG.

Here I am facing big trouble in dealing with telric controls and silverlight controls.
Can somebody please suggest me some ways to overcome it..

Comment: Why do you need to use Selenium RC?

Comment: Its a hell requirement and i cant do anything in it..

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, why do you need to use it? It's deprecated and not used anymore. Does your business have any reason to not use the WebDriver? You are programming in Java, WebDriver has brilliant API's for Java & C#.

Comment: Yeah I understand that..Would u please suggest some gud things with web driver in case of telric controls so that i could suggest them to use it..:(

Comment: You can use Selenium RC's method in WebDriver if there are issues around what you can and cannot do with it. WebDriver has methods that allow you to access the older RC's way of life. WebDriver is faster, you can do much more with it, it is now much more OO based than RC ever was. WebDriver uses browsers automation capability natively, as opposed to using Javascript, you do not need to have a Selenium Server running to use WebDriver.

Answer (score -1):

Selenium is only the way to Automate the Web Application.
Selenium RC cannot handle the special controls which is developed using JQuery/Ajax/Telric
To access these type of controls, it is better to go for Selenium Web Driver-2.0.
At the same time go for Xpath Finder to locate that elements.......